CygWin: Most simple C++ program leads to segmentation fault
I have this very basic C++ program:
#include <iostream>

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    std::cout << "Hello World\n";
}

I compile it with g++ main.cpp -o main and run it with ./main but unfortunately I get:
$ ./main
Segmentation fault

Debugging with gdb:
(gdb) run
Starting program: /cygdrive/c/Users/user/Documents/Projects/tools/test/main
[New Thread 1400.0x1aa4]
[New Thread 1400.0x86c]
[New Thread 1400.0x29d8]
[New Thread 1400.0x5ccc]

Thread 1 "main" received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00000003ef753916 in cygstdc++-6!_ZNSo6sentryC1ERSo () from /usr/bin/cygstdc++-6.dll
(gdb) backtrace
#0  0x00000003ef753916 in cygstdc++-6!_ZNSo6sentryC1ERSo () from /usr/bin/cygstdc++-6.dll
#1  0x00000003ef7d7049 in cygstdc++-6!_ZSt16__ostream_insertIcSt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIT_T0_ES6_PKS3_l ()
   from /usr/bin/cygstdc++-6.dll
#2  0x00000003ef7e6259 in cygstdc++-6!_ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc ()
   from /usr/bin/cygstdc++-6.dll
#3  0x00000001004010ad in main ()

g++-version:
$ g++ --version
g++ (GCC) 13.2.1 20240426
Copyright (C) 2023 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

Loaded libraries:
(gdb) info sharedlibrary
From                To                  Syms Read   Shared Object Library
0x00007fff404f1000  0x00007fff406e7544  Yes (*)     /cygdrive/c/Windows/SYSTEM32/ntdll.dll
0x00007fff40251000  0x00007fff4030c300  Yes (*)     /cygdrive/c/Windows/System32/KERNEL32.DLL
0x00007fff3e0b1000  0x00007fff3e3a5b28  Yes (*)     /cygdrive/c/Windows/System32/KERNELBASE.dll
0x00000003ef6e1000  0x00000003ef8c0eb8  Yes (*)     /usr/bin/cygstdc++-6.dll
0x00000003f5421000  0x00000003f5438018  Yes (*)     /usr/bin/cyggcc_s-seh-1.dll
0x00007ffec4341000  0x00007ffec464e408  Yes         /usr/bin/cygwin1.dll
0x00007fff3e631000  0x00007fff3e6df9ac  Yes (*)     /cygdrive/c/Windows/System32/advapi32.dll
0x00007fff3fed1000  0x00007fff3ff6d4a8  Yes (*)     /cygdrive/c/Windows/System32/msvcrt.dll
0x00007fff3f631000  0x00007fff3f6cf510  Yes (*)     /cygdrive/c/Windows/System32/sechost.dll
0x00007fff40311000  0x00007fff404327cc  Yes (*)     /cygdrive/c/Windows/System32/RPCRT4.dll
0x00007fff3e3b1000  0x00007fff3e3d610c  Yes (*)     /cygdrive/c/Windows/System32/bcrypt.dll
0x00007fff3d3f1000  0x00007fff3d3fb038  Yes (*)     /cygdrive/c/Windows/SYSTEM32/CRYPTBASE.DLL
0x00007fff3e491000  0x00007fff3e511498  Yes (*)     /cygdrive/c/Windows/System32/bcryptPrimitives.dll
0x00007fff31e91000  0x00007fff31ea8050  Yes (*)     /cygdrive/c/Windows/system32/netapi32.dll
0x00007fff31af1000  0x00007fff31b080ac  Yes (*)     /cygdrive/c/Windows/SYSTEM32/SAMCLI.DLL
0x00007fff3dc41000  0x00007fff3dd3faf8  Yes (*)     /cygdrive/c/Windows/System32/ucrtbase.dll
0x00007fff31691000  0x00007fff316b6684  Yes (*)     /cygdrive/c/Windows/SYSTEM32/SAMLIB.dll
0x00007fff3d071000  0x00007fff3d07b02c  Yes (*)     /cygdrive/c/Windows/SYSTEM32/NETUTILS.DLL

Any ideas from you guys what went wrong with my CygWin setup?

can you use info sharedlibrary in gdb when the crash happens to get the loaded libraries, maybe one of them is not from the correct place, this is technically dll hell, so you need to pinpoint the wrong dll.

As mentioned in comments when you asked a virtually identical question yesterday, the problem is almost certainly that components have different (incompatible) versions.   This may be a consequence of "DLL hell" or it may be due to you (or someone) manually updating some components, and introducing incompatibility between versions of components.  Simplest fix would be to uninstall cygwin (and all components) and download/install a single distribution.

while on the topic of determining where dlls are loaded from you can use dependency walker to find all dependencies and their  "default" location where windows will load them if you double click the executable.

@Peter Question yesterday was different as it wasn't based on this very basic program.

@AhmedAEK I added the output of your command

@binaryBigInt  Yes, but the cause is identical.   Something is tweaked (e.g. environment variables) or updated (in a way that introduces incompatibilities).  You really need to fix the cause - install a single distribution, and avoid manual edits.

everything looks fine there, so i think you maybe have a broken install of cygwin.

@Peter Yes you are right. I reinstalled CygWin and now the only g++ version that is available is 11.4.0 and it runs fine now with this version.

I believe that using:
g++ main.cpp -o main -static-libstdc++

should fix the issue. This will statically link the C++ standard library into your executable, potentially resolving any runtime library compatibility issues.

It does indeed - thank you!

Problem with this is that it addresses the symptom, not the cause.   The cause is incompatible versions of components, often due to manually updating components in a way that introduces incompatibility.   If the cause isn't addressed, and updates continue to be done in the same way, eventually the problem will occur again - even with this approach.
